# Invalid regular expression flags error when generating button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the error

> Invalid regular expression flags

From the edit button when I click on it. But HTML output seems to be fine

```
/* EDIT */ {
    mRender: function (data, type, row) {
        var directlink = '/Products/edit/' + row.ArticleID;
        return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' onclick='location.href=" + directlink + "'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'> </i> Edit</button>"
```

**Out come of generated button from JavaScript**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="location.href=/Products/edit/11"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"> </i> Edit</button>
```

Comment: No, that's not "fine". Your assignment statment in that "onclick" handler needs to have a **string** on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the code `onclick='location.href=" + directlink + "'`. Here, `location.href` is assigned a RegEx(Note that regex literal syntax uses `/` as delimiters).

Here, `/Products/edit/11` is read as Regex `/Products/` and `edit` as regex flags, which are Invalid flags(except `i`).

To solve this, the value of the URL can simply be wrapped inside quotes. As both single and double quotes are already used, the quotes need to be escaped.

```
onclick='location.href=\"" + directlink + "\"'
```

If target environment support EcmaScript 6 template literals, you can use

```
return `<button ... onclick='location.href="${directlink}'>...</button>`;
```

---

As, yo're using jQuery, I'd suggest to use it to create new element and bind events on it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the generated button, you are missing the quotes for the string in the assignment on the `onclick` handler

So instead of this:

```
onclick="location.href=/Products/edit/11"
```

It should be this:

```
onclick="location.href='/Products/edit/11'"
```

Since literal regex's uses the `/` javascript assumed it was a regex, hence the error

Comment: Note that OP is already using double quote around the string which is being returned, so, you need to escape it.